# Cannot get contacts from phone book android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm create an application to get all contacts from phone book of Android device. I synch my contacts list from Gmail to android device and I see all contacts in phone book. But when running application, cannot get any contacts from phone book.

Here is my code
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView outputText;
    TextView txtViewContactsInfor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        outputText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtViewContactsInfor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewContactsInfor);
        Import_contacts_from_address_book();
    }


    private void Import_contacts_from_address_book() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PHONECONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String PHONECONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        Uri EMAILCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        String EMAILCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
        String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        System.out.println("---------------------->"+cursor.getCount());
        if(cursor.getCount() >0){
            int aa = cursor.getCount();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                if(hasPhoneNumber > 0 ){
                    output.append("\nFirst Name: "+name);
                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PHONECONTENT_URI, null, PHONECONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n Phone number: "+phoneNumber);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                    // Query and loop for every email of the contact

                    Cursor emailCurosr = contentResolver.query(EMAILCONTENT_URI, null, EMAILCONTACT_ID+"=?",new String[]{contact_id},null);
                    while(emailCurosr.moveToNext()){
                        email = emailCurosr.getString(emailCurosr.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
                        output.append("\nEmail: "+email);
                    }
                    emailCurosr.close();
                }
                output.append("\n");
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        outputText.setText(output.toString());
    }
```

I debug in cursor.getCount and see "544 contact" was found. But 
`int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));`  always zero.

I dont know why.

Comment: Could you update with what `cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)` resolves to by itself, and what `cursor.getString()` resolves to with that previous resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have **a lot** contacts without number, because contacts are stored in multiple columns.

I simplified and modified your code to count rows with and with out numbers and let it run on my phone:

```
private void readContacts() {
    Cursor c = getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int foundWithNumber = 0;
    int foundWithOutNumber = 0;
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idHasNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
        do {
            boolean hasNumber = c.getInt(idHasNumber) > 0;
            if (hasNumber) {
                ++foundWithNumber;
            } else {
                ++foundWithOutNumber;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "foundWithNumber: " + foundWithNumber);
    Log.d(TAG, "foundWithOutNumber: " + foundWithOutNumber);
    c.close();
}
```

The ouput on my phone is:

```
      MainActivity  D  foundWithNumber: 184
                    D  foundWithOutNumber: 303
```

So, I guess, you just looked at the wrong rows. ;)

Comment: Yes, exactly wrong rows, but when I sync from gmail how I know where is the right rows to get it.

Comment: Well, you can select only rows with `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You nead add Read contact permission in Android manifest

> android.permission.READ_CONTACTS